# Modifying SQL dump file

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin, dump

I try to restore Database from dump file, but it only creates tables. Is there a way to modify dump file so it would create databases ?

```
mysql -u ***** -p < localhost.sql
```

Many thanks, Martin.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: How have you created the dump file; through `mysqldump` or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Allready solved, via phpMyAdmin - but i forgot to add create database and use database commands. But i found a script what extracted tables from there, and i restored them one by one :D